# Can laptop supporting 1333MHz DDR3 have one 1333MHz DDR3 + 1600MHz DDR3 RAM

Tags: memory, ddr, sodimm

I have Dell XPS 15 laptop with two RAMs:

- Samsung 4GB
- Corsair 8GB CMSO8GX3M1A1333C9

  DDR3-1333/PC3-10600

  SO-DIMM Memory Module

  204-pin Configuration

  9-9-9-24 CAS Latency

Both these running fine for at least an year.
Now I want to remove 4GB RAM and buy another 8GB one by Corsair. But this one is a bit different model. The specs are as below:

- Corsair 8GB CMSO8GX3M1A1600C11

  DDR3-1600/PC3-12800

  SO-DIMM Memory Module

  204-pin Configuration

  9-9-9-24 CAS Latency

So the only difference between Two corsair's is that the one I currently have is DDR3-1333/PC3-10600, while the one which I am planning to buy is DDR3-1600/PC3-12800. Will these work together well in dual channel?

Comment: [Another](http://superuser.com/questions/585667/upgrading-laptop-ram-dell-xps-15?rq=1) possible duplicate

Answer (score 0):

The faster (1600) RAM will be ran at the lower RAM's speed (1333). You can read up on this on Wikipedia. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-channel_memory_architecture)